# Amending a json query

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to amend a Json with excel vba

i want to be able to change the postcode dynamically with VBA or point this part to a cell in the workbook

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.propertydata.co.uk/prices?key=HEZEHOR0NC&postcode=SW161AG&bedrooms=4")),
    data = Source[data],
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(data)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Comment: the above isn't M not VBA.  If using M then parameterize the string to pick concantenate in the postcode. Your pc_ranges will come out out as list objects. Without knowing how regular the json format is in terms of output by post code vba solutions may not hold across different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes a consistent set of object types within the JSON response and uses XMLHTTP request to get the JSON response. This allows you to use a URL query string that concantenates in the postcode. Tested with a couple of postcodes. It uses a [JSON parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) to handle the JSON. After importing the `JSONConverter.bas` you need to go VBE > Tools > References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime. Unlike you current M code this will list the `pc_ranges` values and not just return a object.

Note: You need to replace `yourKeyGoesHere` with your API key.

```
Option Explicit
Public r As Long
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim jsonStr As String, json As Object, item As Object, output As String
    Dim URL As String, postCode As String
    postCode = "SO419AA" '"SW161AG"
    URL = "https://api.propertydata.co.uk/prices?key=yourKeyGoesHere&postcode=" & postCode & "&bedrooms=4"
    r = 1

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .send
        jsonStr = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)
    emptyObject json
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Sub emptyObject(ByVal json As Object)
    Dim key As Variant, item As Variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each key In json
            Select Case TypeName(json(key))
            Case "String", "Double"
                .Cells(r, 1) = key
                .Cells(r, 2) = json(key)
                r = r + 1
            Case "Dictionary"
                emptyObject json(key)
            Case "Collection"
                For Each item In json(key)
                    Select Case TypeName(item)
                    Case "Double"
                        .Cells(r, 1) = key
                        .Cells(r, 2) = item
                        r = r + 1
                    Case "Dictionary"
                        emptyObject item
                    End Select
                Next
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this please?